# Collapsing ArrayList of objects based on two attributes to generate unique sets

Tags: java, arraylist, set, linkedhashset

I have a particular problem of reorganizing a set of data that I have. Currently my data is held in an ArrayList of the following class:

```
class MyRecord {
    private String location;
    private ArrayList<EmployeeCategory> employeeCategory;}

class EmployeeCategory {
    private String category;
    private String employee;
}
```

such as `ArrayList<MyRecord> myRecordList;`

The data content I have looks like the following (I am presenting it in some JSONlike structure):

```
{location: "Houston", {category: "purchasing", employee: "John"}},
{location: "Houston", {category: "sales", employee: "John"}},
{location: "Houston", {category: "purchasing", employee: "Hank"}},
{location: "Houston", {category: "field operations", employee: "Hank"}},
{location: "Houston", {category: "sales", employee: "Jane"}},
{location: "Houston", {category: "purchasing", employee: "Jane"}},
{location: "Houston", {category: "human resources", employee: "Jane"}},
{location: "Dallas", {category: "purchasing", employee: "Matt"}},
{location: "Dallas", {category: "field operations", employee: "Matt"}},
{location: "Dallas", {category: "human resources", employee: "Todd"}},
{location: "Dallas", {category: "field operations", employee: "Todd"}},
{location: "Dallas", {category: "sales", employee: "Todd"}},
{location: "Dallas", {category: "purchasing", employee: "June"}},
{location: "Dallas", {category: "human resources", employee: "June"}}
```

I would like to simplify that data, and reorganize it into the ArrayList of following class:

```
class MyCollapsedRecord {
    private String location;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> employee;
}
```

so that the data would be in the following form:

```
{location:"Houston", category:"purchasing", employee:["John", "Hank", "Jane"]},
{location:"Houston", category:"sales", employee:["John", "Jane"]},
{location:"Houston", category:"field operations", employee:["Hank"]},
{location:"Houston", category:"human resources", employee:["Jane"]},
{location:"Dallas", category:"purchasing", employee:["Matt", "June"]},
{location:"Dallas", category:"field operations", employee:["Matt", "Todd"]},
{location:"Dallas", category:"human resources", employee:["Todd", "June"]},
{location:"Dallas", category:"sales", employee:["Todd"]}
```

I think best strategy would involve generating unique records based on the pairs of location and category. I have tried using LinkedHashSet while overriding equals and hashValue methods, but I believe my data structures are a little too complex for that kind of application. I think I might need to have a more manual approach with nested for loops such as this [algorithm](http://www.shamasis.net/2009/09/fast-algorithm-to-find-unique-items-in-javascript-array/), but I couldn't wrap my head around to modify it to my more complex case.

Here is my attempt at reorganization so far:

```
ArrayList<MyRecord> myRecordArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
//Load data to myRecordArrayList
ArrayList<CollapsedRecord> myCollapsedArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < myRecordArrayList.size(); i++) {
    boolean isDistinctLocation = false;
    for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
        if (myRecordArrayList.get(i).getLocation().equals(myRecordArrayList.get(j).getLocation())) {
            isDistinctLocation = true;
            for (int m = 0; m < myRecordArrayList.get(i).getEmployeeCategory().size(); m++) {
                boolean isDistinctCategory = false;
                for (int n = 0; n < m; n++) {
                    if (myRecordArrayList.get(i).getEmployeeCategory().get(m).getCategory().equals(myRecordArrayList.get(i).getEmployeeCategory().get(n).getCategory())) {
                        isDistinctCategory = true;
                        CollapsedRecord tempCollapsedRecord = new CollapsedRecord();
                        tempCollapsedRecord.setLocation(myRecordArrayList.get(i).getLocation());                            tempCollapsedRecord.setCategory(myRecordArrayList.get(i).getEmployeeCategory().get(m).getCategory());    
                    }
                }
            }    
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isDistinctLocation) {
        System.out.println(myRecordArrayList.get(i).getLocation());
    }    
}
```

How can it be done?

Comment: *I think best strategy would involve generating unique records based on the pairs of location and category.*: indeed. What is the code you tried to do that?

Comment: I added my code. It became quite convoluted in my head that I need a rest before I look at it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't based on the strategy that you think is the right one:

- define a key, composed of the location and the category, defining hashCode and equals;
- using that key to store all the employees associated to that key.

Just do that, and it will be much simpler:

```
public final class Key {
    private final String location;
    private final String category;

    // TODO constructor, getters, equals and hashCode
}
```

And now just use a Map:

```
Map<Key, List<String>> employeesByKey = new HashMap<>();
for (MyRecord record : myRecordList) {
    for (EmployeeCategory ec : record.getEmployeeCategories()) {
        Key key = new Key(record.getLocation(), ec.getCategory());
        employeesByKey.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<String>()).add(ec.getEmployee());
    }
}

List<MyCollapsedRecord> result = 
    employeesByKey.stream()
                  .map(entry -> new MyCollapsedRecord(entry.getKey().getLocation(), entry.getKey().getCategory(), entry.getValue()));
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How do you define the hashCode based on two variables? Also I didn't use a class of Employee, I would use Map<Key, List<String>> employeesByKey, right?

Comment: Yes, this was a typo. For the hashCode: `return Objects.hash(location, category)`. You could also ask your IDE to generate it (and equals) for you.

Comment: In the second part, (`map(entry -> new MyCollapsedRecord(key.getLocation(), key.getCategory(), value)) `)doesn't work. Says variable (`key`) might not be initialized. Also, what's (`value`) supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry. Typos fixed now.